Chatwoot on CapRover 404 on Password Reset Link
Problem
I've deployed Chatwoot using CapRover.
However, when a new agent clicks the reset password link in the email, they are redirected to a "Nothing here yet :/" (i.e 404 error) page.
My Nginx Config
<%
if (s.forceSsl) {
%>
    server {

        listen       80;

        server_name  <%-s.publicDomain%>;

        # Used by Lets Encrypt
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root <%-s.staticWebRoot%>;
        }

        # Used by CapRover for health check
        location /.well-known/captain-identifier {
            root <%-s.staticWebRoot%>;
        }

        location / {
            return 302 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        }
    }
<%
}
%>


server {

    <%
    if (!s.forceSsl) {
    %>
        listen       80;
    <%
    }
    if (s.hasSsl) {
    %>
        listen              443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate     <%-s.crtPath%>;
        ssl_certificate_key <%-s.keyPath%>;
    <%
    }
    %>

        client_max_body_size 500m;
        underscores_in_headers on;
        server_name  <%-s.publicDomain%>;

        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;
        set $upstream http://<%-s.localDomain%>:<%-s.containerHttpPort%>;

        location / {

        <%
        if (s.redirectToPath) {
        %>
            return 302 <%-s.redirectToPath%>;
        <%
        } else {
        %>

            <%
            if (s.httpBasicAuthPath) {
            %>
                auth_basic           "Restricted Access";
                auth_basic_user_file <%-s.httpBasicAuthPath%>; 
            <%
            }
            %>

                proxy_pass $upstream;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            <%
            if (s.websocketSupport) {
            %>
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
            <%
            }
            %>

        <%
        }
        %>

        }

        # Used by Lets Encrypt
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root <%-s.staticWebRoot%>;
        }
        
        # Used by CapRover for health check
        location /.well-known/captain-identifier {
            root <%-s.staticWebRoot%>;
        }

        error_page 502 /captain_502_custom_error_page.html;
        location = /captain_502_custom_error_page.html {
            root <%-s.customErrorPagesDirectory%>;
            internal;
        }
}

To Reproduce

Deploy Chatwoot on CapRover.
Ensure that HTTPS is set up and functioning properly (also tested without https - same thing).
Invite a new agent to create an account, which sends an email.
Click on the password reset link in the email, e.g., https://example.com/app/auth/password/edit?reset_password_token=userToken

What i've tried so far:
Deploying Chatwoot both with and without HTTPS, but neither worked on my server.
However, when deployed on localhost, the email password reset link worked as expected.
Environment details

CapRover version: 1.11.1
Chatwoot version: 3.11.0
Server OS: Ubuntu 22.04

